# (method) SubscriptionTypeConfigBase<"itemDeleted", unknown>

Tags: nexus, prisma

"nexus": "^1.3.0",
"@prisma/client": "^4.13.0",

How do I resolve the following?

I have defined a graphql subscription as follows:

```
  subscription {
    itemDeleted {
      type
      item {
        id,
        userIdentity
      }
    }
  }
```

and defined my subscription as follows:

```
export const ItemDeletedType = objectType({
  name: 'ItemDeletedType',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.string('type');
    t.nonNull.field('item', { type: types.Item });
  },
});

export const ItemDeleted = subscriptionField('itemDeleted', {
  type: ItemDeletedType,
  subscribe(_root, _args, ctx) {
    return ctx.pubsub.asyncIterator('ITEM_DELETED');
  },
  resolve(payload) {
    return payload;
  },
});
```

but am getting the following error message:

```
(method) SubscriptionTypeConfigBase<"itemDeleted", unknown>.resolve(root: unknown, args: {}, context: any, info: GraphQLResolveInfo): MaybePromise<{
    item: {
        Color: {
            createdAt: Date;
            id: string;
            item: ...[];
            itemvariants: {
                Color: ...;
                Item: ...;
                Size: {
                    ...;
                };
                ... 25 more ...;
                user?: string;
            }[];
            label?: string;
            name: string;
            orderitem: {
                ...;
            }[];
            updatedAt: Date;
        };
        ... 27 more ...;
        userIdentity: string;
    };
    type: string;
}>
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the return type of the resolve function is not matching what is expected. You should make sure that the return type of the resolve function matches the expected type defined in your GraphQL schema.